# Is there any specific time before android automatically closes the application?

Tags: android

As the title says, is there any predefined time set in the operating system that will close any application after some time? in my application I have a process that takes around 5 seconds to complete in pure java. And I know that I should put this in a AsyncTask, just asking the clearify this. Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies from device to device and depends on what is running on the device.

Hope this example gives you a fair idea of what can happen.I'm currently developing an app that uses the camera via intent.

On the Acer Liquid, it went to the camera and returned but on the Sony Ericson Arc, the app was killed in the background almost immediately after the it left my app to go to the camera.

After a restart of the Arc and running the app again, it wasn't killed. Started a few other apps and tried again and it was killed. The Liquid on the other hand would keep the app running four hours in the background even if I started a bunch of other apps.

There is no standard, it varies from device to device, manufacturer to manufacturer and what's currently running at the time.